# SQL table not being created

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I'm Using Oracle.

```
CREATE TABLE  "CUSTOMER" 
(  

"CUS_ID" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "CUSTOMER_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "BIRTH_DATE" DATE, 
    "Mobile_number" NUMBER (10),
    "Number_adopted" (number) (1);
     CONSTRAINT "CUSTOMER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CUS_ID")
     constraint "Email_uni" unique (EMAIL)
     constraint "Mobile_uni" unique (Mobile_number)
     constraint "adopted_range_ck" check ( Number_adopted >=1 and Number_adopted<=4)   USING INDEX  ENABLE
   );
```

I'm getting:

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Also in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE  "ANIMAL" 
   (    "ANIMAL_ID" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "ANIMAL_NAME" VARCHAR2(30),
    "AGE" NUMBER(2),
    "ANIMAL_TYPE" VARCHAR2(30),
    "EXPENCES" NUMBER (10),
    "ADOPTED" VARCHAR2(9),

     CONSTRAINT "ANIMAL_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ANIMAL_ID")
     CONSTRAINT "ANIMAL_EXP_ck check" ( EXPENCES >=1 and EXPENCES<=1000)
     CONSTRAINT "ANIMAL_AGE_ck check" ( AGE >=1)
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   );
```

I'm getting Missing Right Parenthesis error but I'm unable to solve this.

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Comment: it's APEX Oracle

Comment: Oracle is a DBMS, APEX is a UI development tool which is not involved in this question.

Comment: What is the significance of `"Mobile_number"` and `"Number_adopted"` being forced to mixed case while all of the other names are case-insensitive? Double-quoted identifiers are meant for special circumstances, not regular table creation.

Comment: Before asking, do at least some effort to find a solution. In this case you could have started with a table with a single column.  After it works, add another column, add idea, add constraint.

Answer (score 2):

You had a `;` after `"Number_adopted" (number) (1)`, also the parenthesis around `number`are wrong here. Then you've forgotten the `,` after the constraints. If you define a column with `"` around the name and the name is not all upper case, the casing of the individual characters must match in further references and these must also be enclosed in `"`. That's why your `constraint "Mobile_uni" unique (Mobile_number)` had to be changed to `constraint "Mobile_uni" unique ("Mobile_number")`. (But you'll probably want to revise that and make the column names all upper case in the first place. Experience tells me, that such a thing is a future pitfall as you have to exactly use that name in any query etc. and it's hard to notice leaving one wondering why things don't work.) And that `USING INDEX  ENABLE` was misplaced I guess.

```
CREATE TABLE  "CUSTOMER" 
(  

"CUS_ID" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "CUSTOMER_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "BIRTH_DATE" DATE, 
    "Mobile_number" NUMBER (10),
    "Number_adopted" number (1), -- delete ( ) ; add ,
     CONSTRAINT "CUSTOMER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CUS_ID") USING INDEX  ENABLE, --  add ,
     constraint "Email_uni" unique (EMAIL), --  add ,
     constraint "Mobile_uni" unique ("Mobile_number"), -- add ,  " "
     constraint "adopted_range_ck" check ( "Number_adopted" >=1 and "Number_adopted"<=4) -- move USING INDEX  ENABLE add " "
   );
```

In the second one you've also forgotten the `,` after the constraints and had `USING INDEX  ENABLE` misplaced. You also misplaced the `"` for the check constraints and enclosed the keyword `CHECK` in them accidentally.

```
CREATE TABLE  "ANIMAL" 
   (    "ANIMAL_ID" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "ANIMAL_NAME" VARCHAR2(30),
    "AGE" NUMBER(2),
    "ANIMAL_TYPE" VARCHAR2(30),
    "EXPENCES" NUMBER (10),
    "ADOPTED" VARCHAR2(9),

     CONSTRAINT "ANIMAL_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ANIMAL_ID") USING INDEX  ENABLE, -- add ,
     CONSTRAINT "ANIMAL_EXP_ck" check ( EXPENCES >=1 and EXPENCES<=1000), -- add , move "
     CONSTRAINT "ANIMAL_AGE_ck" check ( AGE >=1) -- move "
  -- move USING INDEX  ENABLE
   );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, one more question. Where should I move the using INDEX ENABLE?

Comment: @Fido Dido: Welcome. I moved it after the primary key. See my code snippets above.

Answer (score 1):

I would always define single-column constraints inline with the corresponding column.

Also, double-quoted identifiers are just a source of bugs and inconvenience unless you have a specific reason why you really need a non-standard name. It makes no sense to use them with an all-caps name as that is the default already, so you are just opening up the possibility of bugs creeping in, e.g. if you accidentally name a column `"ANIMAL TYPE"` when you meant `"ANIMAL_TYPE"`. It is generally best to avoid double quotes.

The `using index` clause is for specifying non-default index properties for a unique or primary key (to specify a tablespace, compression options etc). Since you are using the defaults you do not need it.

The `enable` keyword is also the default as constraints are created in an enabled state unless you specify otherwise, so you don't need it.

The `between` keyword saves a lot of typing when specifying inclusive ranges.

There is no requirement to code anything in uppercase. I have no idea why it is so common. Personally I think it's wrong.

```
create table  customer 
( cus_id          varchar2(9)   constraint customer_pk primary key
, customer_name   varchar2(30)
, email           varchar2(30)  constraint email_uni unique
, birth_date      date
, mobile_number   number(10)    constraint mobile_uni unique
, number_adopted  number(1)     constraint adopted_range_ck check (number_adopted between 1 and 4) 
);

create table animal 
( animal_id       varchar2(9)   constraint animal_pk primary key
, animal_name     varchar2(30)
, age             number(2)     constraint animal_age_ck check (age >= 1)
, animal_type     varchar2(30)
, expenses        number (10)   constraint animal_exp_ck check (expenses between 1 and 1000)
, adopted         varchar2(9)
);
```